# Programming through JTAG chain

Tags: jtag

I have this [Zybo Zynq-7000](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/zybo/start) board. The board has a USB interface to configure FPGA as well as JTAG pin headers:

[image: Zybo Zynq-7000]

This is the second board, an [Ultra96-V2](https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us/products/new-product-introductions/npi/aes-ultra96-v2/) which doesn't have a USB to configure FPGA. It only has JTAG pin headers:
[image: Ultra96-V2]
Can I use the JTAG header on the Zybo board to configure FPGA on the Ultra96 board? (My intention is not to buy another [UART to JTAG converter](https://tr.farnell.com/avnet/aes-acc-u96-jtag/usb-to-jtag-uart-pod/dp/2915522) if it is possible "chain" it from the Zybo.)

Answer (score 1):

*Proper* JTAG implementation can be chained as you say. It's called a *scan chain*, after all.

Usually FPGAs and their configuration memories have full JTAGs so it's no problem.

The idea is to chain the TDI to the previous TDO and then 'loop back' the last TDO to the connector. Other signals are simply in parallel. It's like expanding a shift register, simply because the core of JTAG *is* a shift register.

Then you have to say to your programming tool the position of each device in a chain so that it can put in bypass the other ones. That could be tricky since a lot of software is… lets say manufacturers don't like each others.Given that both are Xilinx based tell Vivado or the tool you are using the position and you are set.

There are lots of resources but in your case I'd just pick up UG470 7 Series FPGAs Configuration User Guide and read chapter 9 Chapter 9: Multiple FPGA Configuration, Serial Daisy Chain Configuration (i.e. the *actual configuration manual for your part*)

EDIT: that's assuming that your zybo JTAG is 'openable', it isn't clear from the block diagram and couldn't find any references for it in the manual. Often there are jumpers for that, ask Digilent/NI

Comment: I have to understand if my two FPGA will be identified automatically or not. Or this chain needs to be defined to Vivado explicitly by me?

Comment: What do you mean with 'openable'? There are 6 pins connectors on the board. And relevant selection pin header doing short/open according to the configuration used(JTAG, USB, Flash).

Comment: Probably Vivado will find them correctly; with 'opening' i mean that the TDO from the first board need to be put into TDI of the second and the TDO of the second must go to the JTAG port *instead* of the first one